# TFS, find resolved conflicts in history

Tags: tfs, merge, visual-studio-2013, branching-and-merging

In my team, we are developing using some branch strategy. Sometimes there are conflict in merges which needs to be resolved manually.

Is there a way to get list of these conflicts in history?
We are using TFS 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "get a list of these conflicts in history"?

Comment: If someone manually resolved conflict in changeset xy, someone else resolved another conflict in changeset yxz, I would like to get list of these change sets. (xy and xyz). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this and I doubt you will ever get what you want. The reason I say this is because requiring to resolve merge conflicts is a function of the version of the code each user has on his or her machine. Therefore resolving conflicts is a client side concern which the server has no idea about.